# Hg ACL for cloning

Tags: mercurial, clone, dvcs, acl

Is it possible to use the mercurial ACL extension to prevent specific users from cloning a repository? If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the ACL extension to prevent specific users from cloning.  The `allow_read` and `deny_read` settings in the `[web]` section of a `hgrc` file grant/remove clone rights.  Cloning is really just `hg init ; hg pull` under the covers.

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web